# htaccess rewrite/mask for a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I would like to add to my htaccess file a mask (not sure if this is the right term)

e.g.

In shown in the browser address bar I see:

```
www.newyork.domain-name.com
```

But the content is actually at:

```
www.domain-name.com/group/newyork
```

It will also have to include:

```
www.newyork.domain-name.com/this-is-a-post
```

will be available at

```
www.domain-name.com/group/newyork/this-is-a-post
```

But ignore anything else like:

```
www.domain-name.com
www.domain-name.com/blog
www.domain-name.com/any-url
www.domain-name.com/page/another-page/and/so/on
```

Additionally, is there anything I need to add to my DNS settings at my host and/or in apache?

Comment: How is `www.newyork.domain-name.com` setup in your Apache config?

Comment: I am not sure. I guess that should be a part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to keep same `DocumentRoot` for `www.newyork.domain-name.com` and `www.domain-name.com` in your Apache config.

Once that is setup you can place this rule in your website root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?newyork\.domain-name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!group/newyork/).*)$ group/newyork/$1 [L,NC]
```